# When did stories featuring Martian civilization / life become implausible?

Tags: history-of, mars

So much of classic SF, from Burroughs and Wells onwards, features Mars, Martians, Martian invasions, Martian cities, Martians in the desert, etc.

Obviously, today, this looks like absurd fantasy and no science fiction other than that deliberately doing some sort of homage would today feature present-day Martian life, but *when* did Martian life more substantial than some buried bacteria become understood as plainly absurd? Was this already a disproven conjecture by the time of the Golden Age, or did it manage to persist in some form into the 20th century?

Comment: "Was this already a disproven conjecture by the time of the Golden Age, or did it manage to persist in some form into the 20th century?" Maybe both? The 20th century started in 1901, the Golden Age of Science Fiction was mostly in the 1940s. Anyway, I think this question might be better for some science or history of science site.

Comment: Also, there is quite a big gap between "Martian civilization" and "Martian life more substantial than some buried bacteria". I believe that the idea of Martian vegetation, sufficient to cause seasonal changes in the telescopic appearance of Mars, was a respectable idea right up to the time when we started sending space probes.

Comment: You really mean *currently extant, native* Martian life right? Because life and civilisation on Mars are still staples we've just moved the goal posts towards the archaeological and transplanting some mutation of human civilisation.

Comment: I think a question asking if a civilization on Mars or a planet of Proxima Centauri or some other star is scientifically plausible would be considered off topic for this site, being a question about real science rather than science fiction. I don't see how asking if such an extraterrestrial civilization was scientifically plausible in 1960 or 1940 or 1920 is any different.There are stack exchange sites for questions about science and the history of science.

Comment: @user14111 - Agreed. This question is about what scientists knew (and when), not what science fiction writers knew (and when).

Comment: I've heard that Zelazny's "A Rose for Ecclesiastes" (1963) was his 'farewell' to the old conception of Mars, though I don't have a source for this. It was definitely in the 60s. [The anthology "Farewell Fantastic Venus" (1968) is perhaps relevant in the broader sense - though that's Venus, not Mars, but in the sense of discarding the 'pulp' view of the Solar System...] In the 1970s Leigh Brackett also moved her Eric John Stark, whose stories were originally set in the Solar System, to an extrasolar planet Skaith (*The Ginger Star, The Hounds of Skaith, The Reavers of Skaith*)

Comment: I think the question could be valid if changed to be not so much about the science itself but when writers stopped using a "living" Mars without 'justification' such as alternate history (Turtledove's *A World of Difference*, Stirling's *In the Courts of the Crimson Kings*), future terraforming, the distant past, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the Viking lander in 1976 is the end of fantasy Mars

The first 2 minutes of the 1980 Martian Chronicles movie explicitly says this and salvaged the premise by saying if Viking had landed in a different spot in would have been in a martian city.

Martian Chronicles movie

Of course the Face on Mars is a product of those missions so it didn't end for everyone - but the desolate surface pictures is a nice well defined point to end imagination and replace it with the cold fact of the Martian surface.

Comment: I would say that the Mariner 4 mission which passed close to Mars on July 14, 1965 was the turning point.  It transmitted back pictures of a highly cratered part of Mars with a moonlike look.  More importantly, it also measured the atmospheric density.  I remember reading about experients with keeping multicelled Earth planets and even animals alive with some success in atmospheres like Mars was previusly believed to have, showing believed conditions on Mars were not totally hostile to Earth life.  Then the Mariner probe revealed that the atmosphere was much thinner than believed.

Comment: @M.A.Golding you are correct of course - but I tried to answer it with science fiction rather than focus on real world (the real world aspects of the question got it closed but I think it was on-topic answerable) - and knew Martian Chronicles considered Viking to be the final nail that it *had* to address for the audience to suspend disbelief - which the OP was attempting to get at.